# PDOException SQLSTATE[HY093] after upgrading to PHP 8.1

Tags: php, sql, exception, pdo

today I encounter an issue after upgrading from PHP 7.4 to PHP 8.1.
All the time I was using this code to establish an MySQL connection:

```
<?php

            $kundencode=$_SESSION['kdnr'];
            $i=0;
            $q = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM qi_rechnungen WHERE kdnr='$kundencode' ORDER BY rgnr DESC");
            $q->execute([$_SESSION['id']]);
            $res = $q->fetchAll();
            foreach ($res as $row) {
                $i++;
                ?>
```

This worked fine, but when using PHP 8.1 my system throws:

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in /home/clients-de/public_html/rechnungen2.php:60 Stack trace: #0 /home/clients-de/public_html/rechnungen2.php(60): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 {main} thrown in...

I can't see any mistake!?
What's the difference here between PHP 7.4 and 8.1?

Thank you for help...

Comment: `kdnr='$kundencode'` fix this its causing the error

Comment: You are using prepares wrong, you should not concatenate the value into the query. You should use a placeholder and pass the value in `execute()` as you are. Basically, replace the concatenated value with `?`

Comment: @Dean : Thank you, but I think this can't be the reason. Because when replacing
WHERE kdnr='$kundencode' with WHERE kdnr='4444' (real value) nothing changes.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton : Same with the concantenated value, replaced by "?". No changes, but an additional error:  "Warning: Undefined array key "?" in..."

Answer (score 4):

The change that you encountered is that before PHP 8, PDO's error mode was set to silent by default. If it encountered any errors, it would just ignore them. [This has now changed](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php) to the exception mode; every time an error is encountered, an exception will be thrown. So the issue was there before, it just remained unreported.

About the actual issue: you should really read up about [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php), they will make your code a lot safer. You're not providing any placeholders for prepared variables in your query, but you are passing them in the following line (which results in the exception):

```php
$q->execute([$_SESSION['id']]);
```

As far as I see, the session ID is completely unnecessary for your query, but you could pass your customer number as a variable. The following should fix your issue:

```php
$q = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM qi_rechnungen WHERE kdnr=? ORDER BY rgnr DESC");
$q->execute([$kundencode]);
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you shouldn't inline raw variables in query, use [param binding](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php).

> Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

This means that count of array passed into `PDO::execute()` method is different with count of params in query.

For your case, maybe this solution helps you:

```php
// let's assume there is '5'
$kundencode=$_SESSION['kdnr'];
$q = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM qi_rechnungen WHERE kdnr=:kundencode ORDER BY rgnr DESC");
// pass $kundencode into query
$q->bindValue('kundencode', $kundencode); 
// SELECT * FROM qi_rechnungen WHERE kdnr='5' ORDER BY rgnr DESC
$q->execute();
```

If you want to pass `$_SESSION['id']` into query, you must specify it in query template explicitly

Answer (score -1):

@vixducis : That's exactly what I finally did yesterday - and got it to work as desired:

```
$q = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM qi_domains WHERE kdnr = ? AND aktiv = ? ORDER BY id DESC");
$q->execute([$_SESSION['kdnr'], 0]);
```

So let me thank you all for your kind support!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).